# How can i Edit/Change the value of a model field from views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Good-day everyone. I want to know how i can change the value of a model-field through the number of items in a defined sessions list

I have already made a profile model (which is OneToOne Field to the user model)
with a 'level' field as shown below in my models.py;

And in view.py, I have created a session called 'answer_list' which is a list that stores all correct answers provided by the user.

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')

    level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('Newbie', 'N'), ('Regular', 'R'), ('Expert', 'E')], default='Newbie')
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):

     if 'answer_list' in request.session: #answer_list has been created previously #request.session['answer_list'] = []

        ok = request.session['answer_list']
        print (ok) #just to check the content of 'answer_list' which is correct

            if len(ok) == 4:

                user=request.user

                user.profile.level = 'R'
                user.profile.save()


    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

I want the value of the user.profile.level to change from 'Newbie' to 'Regular' once the number of items in the session 'answer_list' gets to 4. Please how can i go about it

Comment: You didn't save the profile after updating it.

Comment: what is your question ? you are already editing the model field. But as @DanielRoseman said you are not saving it then like this: `user.profile.save()`

Comment: i just added user.profile.save() but the value of the model field did not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(level='R')
```

Comment: @jiaWie Lu , tried that... And I get "UserProfile" object has no attribute "object" error

Comment: Sorry for wrong typing, should be "objects" instead of "object".

Comment: UserProfile.object.filter(user=request.user).update(level='Regular' worked fine... Thanks @JiaWie Lu