# Updating Model Field from Views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a feeling I am missing something obvious and syntax related here so I apologize in advance.

I am attempting to update the status of a user when they successfully process a form.

```
# Models.py
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    status_list = ( ('R',"RED"), ('B',"BLUE"), ('G',"GREEN"),)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_list, default='R')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True)



#Forms.py
class Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('value', )



# Views.py
def View(request):

    if request.POST:
        form = Form(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.initial = {"value": request.POST['value'],}
            form.save()
            # Here is the issue V
            Account.objects.filter(
            status=Account.status).update(status='B')
            return redirect('status')
```

I have tried the solutions presented in both of these two posts:

[1. Editing model field from Views.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422620/how-can-i-edit-change-the-value-of-a-model-field-from-views-py)

[2. Object has no attribute 'update'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304378/django-error-model-object-has-no-attribute-update?answertab=votes#tab-top)

as well as a host of other random and excessively creative combinations.

Does anyone happen to know the proper syntax for this call?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have shown, or any of the other attempts you have made?

Comment: In its current state, I don't get an error message but the status is not updated.

Comment: I think you missed to save the Account after updating the status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Account.objects.filter()` will return a **QuerySet** instead of an Account object. You need to use `get()`, or `filter()[0]` if you know the account exist; if you're not sure whether it exist, you can use `get_or_create()`

If you want to update that specific account status of current user, what you need to do is:

**Step 1: get the account you want to update**

```
# you can get it by searching from Account
account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
# or you can can it directly from the request.uer
account = request.user.account
```

**Step 2: Update the field**

```
account.status = 'B' # set it to whatever you want to update
account.save() # you need to use save() because there is no update() in a model object
```

Comment: Incase anyone uses this for reference in the future: I thought your method of calling directly from request.user was brilliant but I actually only had to call a = request.user since Account doesn't have itself as an attribute. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the changes to the `Account` instance, e.g.

```
def View(request):
  if request.POST:
      form = Form(request.POST, instance=request.user)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.initial = {"value": request.POST['value'],}
          form.save()

          a = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
          a.update(status='B') 
          # or
          #a.status = 'B'
          a.save()
          return redirect('status')
```

and as @MarkLiang pointed out, `filter` returns a QuerySet, not a single
instance of `Account`.