# Create a new table in the view.py in Django

Tags: python, django, view, model

In the document, I can define a table in the `models.py`.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to create a new table in the database.

If I want to create a new table when do something in the `views.py`, is it possible?

For example, I want create a personal table for some new member when he/she register a new account.

Comment: Why don't you create another model based on what you want to store?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422620/how-can-i-edit-change-the-value-of-a-model-field-from-views-py

Answer (score 0):

this is not suggested, standard and neither possible. the tables will be referenced over migrations and will be created by model classes. any table which violate these rules will make you trouble in the future